# Why my Mongoose not working in my every project

Tags: node.js, mongoose

If I use mongoose then mongoose give me this error

QueryCursor.prototype.map = function(fn) {
^

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'map' of object '#'

Comment: If its on your every project that means, the settings and configurations are not right

Comment: Can you show us the code from where that errors comes? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have node version 17.5.0 installed. If so, change it to the last LTS version 16.14.0. I had the same issue, and I resolved it like that.